# How can we use Liquibase Migration for ScyllaDB

Tags: docker, liquibase, scylla

I was reading about Liquibase, and found one related to how we can use Liquibase for Cassandra. I've searched for ScyllaDB but unable to find any help.

How can we use Liquibase for our ScyllaDB Database/Container?

Answer (score 1):

Install Liquibase using your preferred package manager or by downloading it from the Liquibase website. It needs a JDBC driver to connect to ScyllaDB. You can download the driver from the ScyllaDB website and add it to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide me link of any guide? Because I do not find any JDBC driver for scylladb.